# How do i remove the title of a specific org file in the agenda view?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

As it is now, i have my school schedule in an org file. When I use the agenda view, it says "Schedule" (the file name) in front of the schedule entries. I believe that it would look cleaner to remove the file name for that specific file in the agenda view but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

In spite of appearances, that is not the file name: that is the `category`. You can set the category to something different (including the empty string), by adding a `#+CATEGORY` keyword at the beginning of your file. To set it to the emptry string, just say

```
#+CATEGORY:
```

See [Categories](https://orgmode.org/manual/Categories.html#index-category) in the manual.

`CATEGORY` can also be set at the header level via the `PROPERTIES` drawer, e.g.

```
* Foo
:PROPERTIES:
:CATEGORY: Bar
:END:
```